# How to run strace inside CoreOS toolbox container?

Tags: containers, systemd, coreos, strace

I run coreos and need to run strace on a certain process. However:

```
strace -s 99 -ffp 8259
strace: attach: ptrace(PTRACE_SEIZE, 8259): Operation not permitted
```

I opened up the script that spins up the toolbox and found this:

```
sudo systemd-nspawn \
    --directory="${machinepath}" \
    --capability=all \
    --share-system \
    ${TOOLBOX_BIND} \
    --user="${TOOLBOX_USER}" "$@"
```

Which is a namespace container. It looks like a permissions issue but I don't know how to give my container permissions to attach strace to process outside of it. My CoreOS version: `DISTRIB_RELEASE=1185.5.0`

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

Longer answer [here](https://linux-audit.com/protect-ptrace-processes-kernel-yama-ptrace_scope/)

Comment: They don't have a yama kernel module included. And no gcc compiler on CoreOS of course. How do I do that?

Comment: What does "ls -la /proc/sys/kernel/yama/" return?

Comment: "ls -la /proc/sys/kernel/yama/" If the module is not installed, it is probably natural that any associated yama files don't exist.